# Проблема при сборке приложения без студии

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-resources

Собираю приложение без студии и градл. Хочу разобраться, как всё работает из коробки.

Итак, у меня есть проект, и появилась проблема с использованием библиотеки **android/support/design**. У меня получилось собрать проект с использованием библиотек **android/support/v7/appcompat** и  **android/support/v7/recyclerview** без проблем -  всё отображается и работает. А потом начались проблемы именно с **android/support/design**

Сейчас сделал проект, в котором просто **AppCompatActivity**, а его контентвью - это **FrameLayout** с **FloatingActionButton** внутри. При сборке никаких ошибок нет, а при запуске выдаёт ошибку при выполнении **setContentView** у активити "*java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity*"

1. в манифесте установлена у application тема, наследуемая от
   Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
2. это работает без ошибок при сборке из студии

Сижу в гугл и SO уже около недели. Информацию именно по этому поводу найти почему-то непросто. Находил ссылки подобные:
[android-aapt-merging-resources-from-libraries](http://www.timelesssky.com/blog/android-aapt-merging-resources-from-libraries), но именно с **android/support/design** проблему пока не решил

Я делаю так:

- собираю ресурсы с помощью \build-tools\23.0.3\aapt
- классы с помощью javac
- декс с помощью \build-tools\23.0.3\dx
- делаю apk с помощью \build-tools\23.0.3\aapt

потом подпись и установка\переустановка

Прилагаю к вопросу архив [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r08njofm4na8vwq/design_so.rar?dl=0). Чтобы собрать приложение, нужно поочерёдно запустить скрипты (соответственно заменить пути к утилитам):
 - clear.bat
 - r_des.bat
 - c_des.bat
 - d_des.bat
 - a_des.bat
 - sign.bat

Потом чтобы запустить на устройстве (ошибка проявляется после сборки)
 - install.bat

Comment: Попробуйте другие версии библиотек. А вообще - зачем вам так страдать и не делать через студию? Никакого эзр=отерического знания вы таким путём не получите, а нервов много изведёте.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб чтоб автосборку на сервере настроить, например.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб для меня принципиально - с именно этой библиотекой градл собирает проект нормально. Я хочу узнать как

Comment: @Suvitruf автосборка на сервере делается через градл, на худой конец по старинке каким нибудь антом. Какой смысл пытаться сделать свою очередную систему сборки для меня загадка

Comment: @xkor велосипедолюбители.